# Possibilities to mark only one entry in database table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am working on some kind of a topiclist. It can have multiple topics and each topic can have multiple subtopics. You can also vote for each subtopic if you like it or not, but i don't think this is relevant for the question.

So my two relevant database tables are `topics` and `subtopics`.

Here are simplified versions of them:

```
CREATE TABLE topics (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE subtopics (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    topic_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(topic_id)
    REFERENCES topics(id)
);
```

I want to add a possibility to mark a subtopic, that it is prioritized, but there should always just be one prioritized subtopic for each topic.

Do you have any suggestions how to realize that?

My idea would be to add another field to `subtopics` with a timestamp, which gets updated to the current time, when you mark it as prioritized. When you select the entries, you just have to look for most recent timestamp.

Are there any other (better) possibilities?

I am working with PHP and MySQL

Comment: Your idea of using a timestamp to represent the prioritized subcategory (within each category) sounds clever and great to me.  I was heading down the road of using a boolean to represent the prioritized filed, but this runs into problems of maybe having to use a transaction to keep things consistent.  With the timestamp, you guarantee (in theory) that only one subcategory will be prioritized, and it's much harder to break things.

Comment: I would maybe use a third table "priorities" containig the topic and the subtopic id. Then you can join with this table etc.

Comment: If you van have only one prioritised subtopics per topic, then just add one field to the topics table that holds the id of the subtopic that is prioritised. You can also store these in a separate table with a unique index on the topic id field to ensure that no topic can have more than one priority subtopic.

Comment: @Shadow: This will only work if topics and subtopics have a 1:n relationship but not in case of n:n., i.e. one subtopic can belong to multiple topics.

Comment: @user1915746 1) Based on the question, it is a 1:n relationship, not n:m. 2) Even if the relationship were n:m, so what? The requirement is to have maximum one prioritised subtopic per topic. The question did not say not say anything about restricting the number of topics a subtopic could be prioritised for.

Comment: @Shadow there can also be no prioritized topic, I know you could probably also just let the field be empty, but anyway, I'll go with my own idea, thanks for your help!

Comment: This question is an excellent demonstration why design questions are not really for SO. Opinions weigh too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I will go with my own idea from above:

> My idea would be to add another field to `subtopics` with a timestamp, which gets updated to the current time, when you mark it as prioritized. When you select the entries, you just have to look for most recent timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add three field priority,vote,timestamp into subtopics table.

priority field would be 0 or 1 that means 1 is proritized and 0 is not.
 vote would be 0 or 1 that means 1 is liked and 0 is not liked.
 timestamp contain time when you mark subtopic as prioritized.